# How to read process memory with Base adress and Pointers

Tags: c#, memory, memory-address

I have been working on a small project - I am trying to create a C# program that will read the character's HP from a game "League Of Legends".

I did some research and after some time messing around with cheatengine, I got the offsets that will point to the HP's address even after restarting the PC, and I can successfully read it every time.

[image: CE]

Now I wanted to make a program that would do the same thing. I found a Class that I could read the float's from memory with, called [VAMemory](http://www.vivid-abstractions.net/logical/programming/vamemory-c-memory-class-net-3-5/). I copypasted the static address from Cheatengine to my program and got the HP value, like I wanted.

```
VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("League Of Legends");
vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)adress);
```

But this does not work after restarting the game, so I would have to get the address from Cheatengine again.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847107/using-base-pointers-with-offset-to-read-process-memory) and the answer said:

> For each level you have to read the memory and see what is stored at the address. The value you find will be your next address, to which you apply your next offset, and so on.

In this question, the asker had 2 offsets, but I have 5?

Used this to get the base address:

```
 Process GameProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("League Of Legends").FirstOrDefault();
 IntPtr BaseAddress = GameProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress;
```

So then I created this monstrosity:

```
 try
        {


            Process GameProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("League Of Legends").FirstOrDefault();
            VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("League Of Legends");

            IntPtr BaseAddress = GameProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress;
            float Basevalue = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)BaseAddress);
            abase.Text = BaseAddress.ToString();
            vbase.Text = Basevalue.ToString();

            IntPtr Basefirst = IntPtr.Add(BaseAddress, 0x658);
            float Basefirstvalue = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)Basefirst);
            a1.Text = Basefirst.ToString();
            v1.Text = Basefirstvalue.ToString();

            IntPtr Basesecond = IntPtr.Add(IntPtrFromFloat(Basefirstvalue), 0x150);
            float Basesecondvalue = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)Basefirstvalue);
            a2.Text = Basesecond.ToString();
            v2.Text = Basesecondvalue.ToString();

            IntPtr Basethird = IntPtr.Add(IntPtrFromFloat(Basesecondvalue), 0x0);
            float Basethirdvalue = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)Basethird);
            a3.Text = Basethird.ToString();
            v3.Text = Basethirdvalue.ToString();

            IntPtr Basefourth = IntPtr.Add(IntPtrFromFloat(Basethirdvalue), 0x44);
            float Basefourthvalue = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)Basefourth);
            a4.Text = Basefourth.ToString();
            v4.Text = Basefourthvalue.ToString();

            IntPtr Basefifth = IntPtr.Add(IntPtrFromFloat(Basefourthvalue), 0x36c);
            float Basefifthvalue = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)Basefirst);
            a5.Text = Basefifth.ToString();
            v5.Text = Basefifthvalue.ToString();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
    static IntPtr IntPtrFromFloat(float f)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            return (*(IntPtr*)&f);
        }
    }
```

- It takes the base address, adds the first offset, [reads the value, adds next]x5 and then reads the last address, but unfortunately its value is 0.

Instead of the beautiful numbers in Cheatengine I got this:[image: numbers]
I have been messing with this thing for a long time, but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong?

How can I get the dynamic address from the base address and [Pointers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8HmR.png)?

UPDATE:

I am now using new pointers:
[image: new pointers]

And I changed the code according to the comments,
It Uses Readint32() instead of readfloat() and looks much cleaner:

```
Process GameProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("League Of Legends").FirstOrDefault();
            VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("League Of Legends");

            IntPtr BaseAddress = GameProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress;

            IntPtr Base1 = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(BaseAddress), 0x58);

            IntPtr Base2 = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base1), 0xC0);

            IntPtr Base3 = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base2), 0x118);

            IntPtr Base4 = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base3), 0x39C);

            IntPtr Base5 = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base4), 0xBC);

            float value = vam.ReadFloat(Base4);

            Lvalue.Text = value.ToString();
```

BUT, it still does not work. I ran Cheatengine simultaneously and it got the right address and value, but my program got these: 
[image: debug]
and the final value is 0, it should be 528.

Comment: Don't put code as links to Pastebin, put it in the question itself. People should not need to click a external link to fully understand your problem.

Comment: That being said, your problem is you call `vam.ReadFloat`, on every level, you should only be calling ReadFloat once at the end, the inbetween levels need to be using `vam.ReadInt32(` to get the next layer down. Each level should look like `IntPtr Basesecond = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Basefirst), 0x150);`

Comment: `IntPtr Basethird = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Basesecond), 0x0);`, `IntPtr Basefourth = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Basethird), 0x44);`, `IntPtr Basefifth = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Basefourth), 0x36c);`, `float Basefifthvalue = vam.ReadFloat(Basefifth);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My orginal comment as an answer:

Your problem is you call `vam.ReadFloat`, on every level, you should only be calling `ReadFloat` once at the end, the in between levels need to be using `vam.ReadInt32(` to get the next layer down.

```
Process GameProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("League Of Legends").FirstOrDefault();

VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("League Of Legends");

IntPtr Base = GameProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress;
IntPtr BaseFirst = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base), 0x658);
IntPtr Basesecond = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Basefirst), 0x150);
IntPtr Basethird = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Basesecond), 0x0);
IntPtr Basefourth = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Basethird), 0x44);
IntPtr Basefifth = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Basefourth), 0x36c);
float Basefifthvalue = vam.ReadFloat(Basefifth);

Lvalue.Text = Basefifthvalue.ToString();
```

---

The problem with your updated answer is you have a typo.

```
float value = vam.ReadFloat(Base4);
```

should be

```
float value = vam.ReadFloat(Base5);
```

Also, I was not familiar with Cheat Engine's UI but it appears you are doing the things in reverse, `0xBC` should be the offset of the first value and `0x58` should be the amount you add to the last value.